# Unexpected error in example using example from MSDN Image Encoding - GetEncoderParameterList

Tags: c#, list, encoding, parameters

This code was inserted in a button handler.

It gives different errors if I compile the project for x64 or x86

x64 : Gives the Overflow Exception unhandled

Explanation: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

x86 : Gives Bitmap region is already locked.

Suggestion : If you are using a Graphics object after the GetHdc Method, call the ReleaseHdc Method

Code:

```
Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(10, 10);
        ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        EncoderParameters paramList = bitmap1.GetEncoderParameterList(jpgEncoder.Clsid);
        EncoderParameter[] encParams = paramList.Param;
        StringBuilder paramInfo = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < encParams.Length; i++)
        {
            paramInfo.Append("Param " + i + " holds " + encParams[i].NumberOfValues +
                " items of type " +
                encParams[i].ValueType + "\r\n" + "Guid category: " + encParams[i].Encoder.Guid + "\r\n");

        }
```

Line giving error is:

```
EncoderParameters paramList = bitmap1.GetEncoderParameterList(jpgEncoder.Clsid);
```

Any idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected "Bitmap Region is already Locked" exception with GetEncoderParameterList. Any ideas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152506/unexpected-bitmap-region-is-already-locked-exception-with-getencoderparameterli)

Comment: Yes I saw the post now, so I should only avoid to use the GetEncoderParameterList for Jpeg codec in (win7 sp1), how do I get the parameters list for usage then, any list available somewhere ?

Comment: Just specify the parameter you want to set directly.

Comment: I suppose the full list of the parameters is codec dependant, so if I can't get the list for jpeg how do I know what are all the parameters it has. Is there any list available somewhere ?

Comment: If you don't know what parameter you want to set then the full list isn't going to bring much clarity.  This of course is why nobody else has this problem.