# System.Drawing image colors are not matching web colors

Tags: c#, system.drawing

i have this simple code for image creating

```
Color clr = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0000ff");
using (var bm = new Bitmap(100, 100)) {
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
        g.Clear(clr);
    bm.Save("e:\\blue-square.gif", ImageFormat.Gif);
    bm.Save("e:\\blue-square.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    bm.Save("e:\\blue-square.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

and here is an example

[image]

Why colors in png and jpg are different from html #0000ff color?
How to create transparent png with colored element in it with correct color?

**update 1**

`Bitmap.Save(ImageFormat)` has default parameters and i've done some research in this direction.

I decided to start with jpg and my goal is clean `#0000ff` after save.

There is another save method `Bitmap.Save(ImageCodecInfo,EncoderParameters)`
and nice example about jpeg quality
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/bb882583(v=vs.110).aspx

I've tried `100L` but this is not solve my problem - the color is #0000fe instead of #0000ff

It seems i have to set some other parameters in `EncoderParameters` object.

I read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/bb882589(v=vs.110).aspx
and this
[Unexpected "Bitmap Region is already Locked" exception with GetEncoderParameterList. Any ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152506/unexpected-bitmap-region-is-already-locked-exception-with-getencoderparameterl)

jpeg still no success

**update 2**

I tried png and custom palette with pixel format `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed`
and result was the same: `#3000fe`

Comment: Using `Bitmap.Save(ImageFormat)` does not give you complete control over the compression process. If you save it as a 24-bit/32-bit PNG file then it should be the same, but 8-bit PNG (color table mode) should still be able to save it exactly (as you're using less than 256 colors). Similarly a suitable JPEG compression quality setting (80+) should preserve the original color.

Comment: @Dai I see, thank you. Tried jpeg 100 with no success

Comment: @Dai tried 8bit png with no success. get color 3000fe instead of 0000ff :-/

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue of image compression algorithms

Comment: PNG should be lossless as far as I know

Comment: @PaulStelian yes, it's lossless, but it is compressed format.

Comment: What does lossless mean? It means that the data is not changed (colors shall remain identical)

Comment: PNG has been created as a lossless format. But in some circumstances it becomes lossy for exact colors, due to avaraging filter.

Comment: @Yuri is there any workaround for getting correct colors in png?

Comment: As far as I know - there are no workarounds with System.Drawing. Probably, some 3d party libraries can help (like http://imageprocessor.org/). But sometimes I'm facing this issue even in Photoshop.